# Can you check multiple values of a variable in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm working a chess program and I was wondering if I could make a process a little easier by checking bpawn1 - bpawn8's x position and y position and seeing if the x and y positions are the same as the white pawn and is so it kills the pawn.

```
class ChessPeice:
    def __init__(self, color, x_position, y_positon):
        self.color = color
        self.x = self.x_position
        self.y = self.y_position

    @staticmethod
    def move(x_position, y_position):
        pass

class WPawn(ChessPeice):

    def move(x_position, y_position):
        if self.x_position + 1 == x_position and self.y_position == y_position:
            self.x_position += 1
        elif self.x_position + 1 == x_position and self.y_position + 1 == y_position:
            if self.x_positon + 1 == bpawn1.x_position and self.y_positon + 1 == bpawn1.y_position
            bpawn1 == "dead"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be what you're looking for?

```
In [15]: pawn_pos = (1, 3)

In [16]: rook_pos = (4, 6)

In [17]: pawn_pos == rook_pos
Out[17]: False

In [18]: rook_pos = (1, 3)

In [19]: pawn_pos == rook_pos
Out[19]: True
```

Alternatively, you could override the `__eq__` method.

```
In [26]: class ChessPiece:
    ...:     def __init__(self, color, x, y):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:         self.y = y
    ...:         self.color = color
    ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
    ...:         return (self.x, self.y) == (other.x, other.y)
    ...:     

In [27]: c1 = ChessPiece('black', 1, 3)

In [28]: c2 = ChessPiece('white', 1, 4)

In [29]: c1 == c2
Out[29]: False

In [30]: c2 = ChessPiece('white', 1, 3)

In [31]: c1 == c2
Out[31]: True
```